# Add number of days to current date and store it in db

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have created a form as follows. In EDOC field when the user specifies 2days and it should add to the current date and it should store in phpmyadmin.
Here is my code. **I want this date to be added in m/d/y format. In phpmyadmin I changed the brower transformation as Text/Plain:Dateformat and transformation option as 0,'%b-%d-%Y','local'.

It is adding and it is showing in popup box but, in db it is storing some junk date. So before inserting into db I should convert this into another date format how?**

Please answer this question.

Thank you.

**Home.php**

```
  <form action="Confirm.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
Expected Date : <input name="edoc" type="text" id="edoc" size="15" maxlength="40" value=""/>
    <button id='send' type='submit'>Add</button>
</form>
```

**Confirm.php**

```
      <form action="Add.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
Expected Date :     
<?php include_once('dbconn.php'); ?>
          <input name="edoc" type="text" id="edoc" size="15" readonly="readonly" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo $_POST['edoc']; ?>"/>
    <button id='send' type='submit'>Confirm</button>
</form>
```

**dbconn.php**

```
<?php 
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$selected = mysql_select_db("eservice",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select database");
?>
```

**Add.php**

```
<?php
include_once('dbconn.php');
session_start();
$_SESSION['example']='Session Created';
    $edoc = $_POST['edoc'];
    $current = date('m/d/y');
    $date = strtotime("+".$edoc." days", strtotime($current));
    $ecd  = date("m/d/Y", $date);
if($edoc !='')
{
$insQry = "Insert into 'main'(edoc) Values('$ecd');
$insertQ = mysql_query($insQry);
} ?>
<script language="javascript">
    alert("Task created successfully" + "\n" + " <?php echo $ecd; ?>");
    top.location.href = "Form.php"; //the page to redirect
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp

> SELECT OrderId,DATE_ADD(OrderDate,INTERVAL 45 DAY) AS OrderPayDate
>   FROM Orders

it also works with other kinds of time intervals eg. seconds, hours and years.

Answer (score 0):

Just write this simple line in place your two variable $date and $edc

```
$date = date('m/d/y',strtotime('+2 days')); //Whatever days you want, it can be dynamic also
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the format i.e,

Before - $ecd = date("**m/d/Y**",$date);
After  - $ecd = date("**Y/d/m**",$date);

It worked perfectly.

Thanks.

```
$edoc = $_POST['edoc'];

$current = date('m/d/Y');
$date = strtotime("+".$edoc." days", strtotime($current));
$ecd  = date("Y/m/d", $date);

$reviewed = $_POST['reviewed'];

$path   = $_POST['path'];
```